# Detect The Beginning Of An Instagram Live

Tags: python, instagram

I've been looking for a way to detect the beginning of an Instagram Live and send a message/notification when it happens. Automatic notifications have never worked for me.

I've looked at the API and some other stuff but no success there. Could you guys share your ideas on how I could achieve that goal? Ideally from a list of followed accounts, detect if any of them goes live and send a notification.